# Finding summation as n tends to infinity

Tags: limits, summation

Can I claim for the following

$$\lim_{\text n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\text 1_k}{n}=1$$

Since

$$\lim_{\text n \rightarrow 4}\sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{\text 1_k}{n}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=1$$

$$\lim_{\text n \rightarrow 5}\sum_{k=1}^5 \frac{\text 1_k}{n}=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}=1$$

Comment: what do you mean by $1_k$?   I don't understand the notation.

Comment: Number of times 1 occurs according to the n

Comment: Did you mean $\sum_{k=1}^n$ in the first display?

Comment: Yes! That is what I am trying to say,

Comment: But the two other limits are 0, because they are a constant times $1/n$. I don't understand the notation maybe

Comment: Why not write the sum as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}$ and drop the $\lim$ in the other two cases as that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am trying to mean something like this $$\lim_{n \rightarrow 5}\sum_{k=1}^{5}\frac{1_k}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{5}\frac{1_k}{5}=\frac{1_1}{5}+\frac{1_2}{5}+\frac{1_3}{5}+\frac{1_4}{5}+\frac{1_5}{5}=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}$$

Comment: @Crazy Drop the $k$ from $1_k$ it doesn't change anything also instead of $\lim_{n\to 5}$ just write $\sum_{k=1}^5\frac{1}{5}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n1}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$$

**Note:** You need not write things like $1_k$. $\sum_{k=1}^n1$ means itself "summing $1$ $n$ times".